# R | Merge dataframes on all shared columns but do not drop not-shared columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I need to merge several dataframes in R. the dataframes have a lot of overlapping columns, but not all of them, and the columns are not necessarily in the same order. Is there a function in R that does the following:

- Recognize which columns are shared by the dfs (based on same col name)
- create new columns for columns that are not shared
- bind the dfs (like rbind())

Let's say we have three dataframes:

**df_2016:**

| year | id | fav_food |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | 1001 | bread |
| 2016 | 1010 | pizza |
| 2016 | 1003 | spaghetti |

**df_2017:**

| year | id | fav_movie |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 1001 | lotr |
| 2017 | 1020 | inception |
| 2017 | 1021 | jurassic_park |

**df_2018:**

| year | id | degree |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 1001 | BS |
| 2018 | 1010 | MS |
| 2018 | 1011 | Highschool |

*Desired Output*
**df_2016_2018:**

| year | id | fav_food | fav_movie | degree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | 1001 | bread | NA | NA |
| 2016 | 1010 | pizza | NA | NA |
| 2016 | 1003 | spaghetti | NA | NA |
| 2017 | 1001 | NA | lotr | NA |
| 2017 | 1020 | NA | inception | NA |
| 2017 | 1021 | NA | jurassic_park | NA |
| 2018 | 1001 | NA | NA | BS |
| 2018 | 1010 | NA | NA | MS |
| 2018 | 1011 | NA | NA | Highschool |

**Is there a way to do this?**
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = "^df_\\d{4}$")))
```

-output

```
 year   id  fav_food     fav_movie     degree
1 2016 1001     bread          <NA>       <NA>
2 2016 1010     pizza          <NA>       <NA>
3 2016 1003 spaghetti          <NA>       <NA>
4 2017 1001      <NA>          lotr       <NA>
5 2017 1020      <NA>     inception       <NA>
6 2017 1021      <NA> jurassic_park       <NA>
7 2018 1001      <NA>          <NA>         BS
8 2018 1010      <NA>          <NA>         MS
9 2018 1011      <NA>          <NA> Highschool
```